# How do I project to a dictionary with a custom type using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I am attempting to use Linq to project each row from a DB query into a dictionary that has a custom type as its value. I am unsure of the LINQ syntax to do this?

This is my current attempt (which doesn't compile, but should demonstrate what I am trying to do). I am having trouble with the 'select new...' part.

```
public class MyClass
{     
   public Dictionary<int, CustomType> dict;
}

public class MyType{        
   string Name;
   decimal Value;
}

var result = (from t in table
              select new {
                 t.Id,
                 new MyType(t.Name,t.Value)
              }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary();
```

ANSWER:

Thanks Jason. I just used properties and automatic initialisers rather than a constructor. The working code resembles this (any improvements to this are welcome):

```
public class MyType {        
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Value { get; set;}
}

Dictionary<int, CustomType> dict;

dict = (from t in table
        select new {
           id = av.Account.Id,
           mt = new MyType { Name = t.Name, Value = t.Value }
        }).ToDictionary(item => item.id, item => item.mt);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyType` doesn't have a constructor that takes two arguments.

Add the following to the definition of `MyType`:

```
public MyType(string name, decimal value) {
    Name = name; 
    Value = value;
}
```

Further, you did not give the anonymous type member defined by

```
new MyType(t.Name, t.Value)
```

a name; try changing that line to:

```
MyType = new MyType(t.Name, t.Value)
```

The compiler will yell at you that it can not discern a name for this anonymous member.

Finally, there isn't an overload of `ToDictionary` that has no arguments. Assuming you named the above anonymous member to be `MyType`, change the call to `ToDictionary` to be

```
....ToDictionary(item => item.Id, item => item.MyType);
```